# Help finding a short story/excerpt about a "Great Game"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

I need help finding a short story/excerpt I remember reading in a "best of sci-fi year?" omnibus

I remember the setting being about a future great game between great powers involving Great Britain, which the main character is a citizen and soldier (mention of a "dragoons?" uniform) of. He visits a embassy on a mission and sees a girl that is a special type of person that can lock information in their subconscious. That's vaguely what I remember.

Comment: This reads like the 'blurb for Catherine Drewe by Paul Cornell. I have it as an ebook but haven't yet read it so am reluctant to go online for more details in case I spoil it for myself!

Comment: Do you know were i can purchase the ebook? Edit: Nevermind found it, thank you very much bellatrix.

Comment: He has other  stories set in the same alternate universe. I've got three but so far have only read what I think is the second one "One of our B*sta**ds is Missing"

Comment: Its called the Johnathan Hamilton series

Answer (score 3):

["Catherine Drewe"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?974238), a short story by [Paul Cornell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Cornell), appeared in the anthology [*The Year's Best Science Fiction & Fantasy*, 2009 Edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?305032) edited by [Richard Horton](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?31345). The story is available for free [here](http://pyrsamples.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/fast-forward-2-catherine-drewe-by-paul.html).

Excerpts from story (emphasis added):

> The Porters, in all their multitudes, ran out of their lodge as he cut the engine and sailed into the quad, but the sight of the Fourth **Dragoons** badge had them doffing their caps and applauding.
>
> [. . . .]
>
>  “This thing will tip the balance. You can’t be the only one who’s intuited it’s here. Whoever gets it gains a decisive advantage. It’ll be the end of **the Great Game**—”

Comment: Can you explain why this is the correct answer?

Comment: As I mentioned in comments I have this story but it's still in my TBR stack. I only went by the OP description and it matching  the 'blurb I have for that story. I'm reluctant to go deep into finding all the key points as that would be a spoiler for me.